# Проблема с русскими буквами в IE.

Tags: кодировка, html, php

Здравствуйте.
В данный момент делаю сайт, на котором с помощью AJAX`а передается GET-запрос PHP-Файлу и этот файл возвращает результат. Это дело осуществляется при регистрации, вводе данных в поля формы и динамической проверке этих самых данных. В форме надо указать, к примеру, имя на русском языке. Имя отсылается Get-запросом к обработчику, но...вместо введенного в форму имени ajax`ом отсылаются знаки вопросов. ПРИЧЕМ это только в IE, т.е во всех остальных браузерах такой фигни не наблюдается. Все файлы в кодировке UTF-8. Уже много чего перепробовал: указывать кодировку в HTACCESS`е, юзать mb_string, но ничего с этим дурацким IE не выходит...помогите пожалуйста.

---

Здесь скорее проблема в кодировке GET-запроса, нежели в кодировке самого сайта...

Comment: попробуй установи кодировку в самом IE на UTF-8

Comment: он то сможет - а вот юзверю это зачем делать? ему легче уйти с сайта :). По теме - может в шаблоне что нибудь намутил не то?

Comment: нифига себе) и что, каждого юзера просить "Установите пожалуйста кодировку своего долбаного IE в UTF-8, а то наш сайт не предусмотрен для IE" ?

Comment: @Darix, ну не знаю даже...а что например?

Comment: кодировка в <meta> ^^ мало ли забыл :) у меня так было пару раз ;D
весь сайт сделал на UTF а в шаблоне был cp1251 и потом сильно удивлялся когда вместо букв видел заклинания на не понятном языке :D

Comment: К счастью, этого я не забыл)

Comment: Ну так что? Никто не знает что ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мде... Это тема, как я понял, вечная и самое главное то, что нет универсального способа. У каждого есть какой-то скрытый "подводный камень". Пробуйте каждый или в совокупности способы:

a) Установить локаль

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, array('ru_RU.CP1251', "ru_RU","ru","rus_RUS"));
```

b) В .htaccess строка

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

c) После подключения к базе:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

d) Принимая параметр или при ответе - перекодировать данные:

```
$data= iconv("cp1251","UTF-8",$data);
```

Даже можно сделать простенькую проверку на кодировку перед этим

```
if (!preg_match('//u', $data)) {
        $data= iconv("cp1251","UTF-8",$data);
}
```

e) На серверной части прописать:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

а у кого-то может сработать наоборот

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Comment: Спасибо, что вы ответили. Я уж было подумал, что кодировка - это что-то сверхсложное...Я пробовал два основных метода преобразования - setlocale, iconv и AddDefaultCharset UTF-8. В итоге кое-как сработала iconv, но она сработал так, что в IE вроде бы все нормально преобразовывается, а вот в Chrome, Opera, Mozilla - отстой, ничего не получилось...может это проблема в кодировке моего ajax GET запроса? Как думаете?

Comment: Не исключаю. Возможно кодировку надо преобразовывать уже при отправке данных через ajax

Кстати, встречал ОЧЕНЬ загадочный способ решения проблемы. Сам не проверял, но пусть как бредовый, но вариант:

    <script src="example.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Ой, спасибо вам огромное за столь прекрасную статью на хабре!!! Пускай благословит бог автора этой статьи. Все дело оказалось в кодировании отсылаемых данных JS-функцией "encodeURIComponen" -  я её просто не использовал...еще раз большое вам спасибо!

**P.S** Как вы только все эти статьи выискиваете =)

Comment: Вопрос риторический ;)

Comment: Все равно вы мне очень помогли с этой статьей ;)